# Docker arguments work w/ COPY but not ADD

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

Got this solved!

I learned my smart quotes lesson the hard way...

Although, now that I know this- I find it crazy that Docker themselves used smart quotes in this tutorial: https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-dockerize-your-python-applications/

---

Just want to figure this out for my edification..

Just learning Docker and getting a "Hello World" in Python working...

My Dockerfile:

```
# FROM python:3.11
# ADD main.py .
# CMD [“python”, “./main.py”]

FROM python:3.11
COPY main.py .
CMD ["python", "./main.py"]
```

Main.py

```
print("Hello World")
```

It works fine with COPY (as is), but when I build/run with ADD I get:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [“python”,: not found
```

What am I missing?

From what I understand, these should be doing the same thing...

Comment: Note: Smart quotes vs. programming quotes are very different things. You have both in your question. Is that what you're seeing, or an artifact of how it got copy-pasted?

Comment: I tend to specify the full path of things, so like `CMD [ "/usr/bin/python", ... ]` to be absolutely sure it doesn't miss. The container you're using should have that `PATH` set correctly, though, so that may not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the ADD or COPY causing this issue, it's the two different CMD statements you're using:

- `CMD [“python”, “./main.py”]`
- `CMD ["python", "./main.py"]`

Replace the smart quotes with normal quotes, and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks! Yet another lesson learned the hard way :)

Comment: @CaseyCushing it doesn't matter where in the stack you work, or what decade you where born in, one day smart quotes will screw you. The earlier in your career it happens, the better :D

Comment: I hear that! I figure that what screwed me is this tutorial, from docker.com themselves! https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-dockerize-your-python-applications/

They use smart quotes!

Comment: Of all the badly named things in tech "Smart Quotes" are certainly up there.